# Searching for a keyword in a text file

Tags: php, search

I'm working on a PHP search script that scans a text file repository of packages on a website and returns the URL of each match. The text files looks as followed:

```
PACKAGE NAME: package_one
PACKAGE LOCATION: ./package_one
PACKAGE VERSION: 0.1.2

PACKAGE NAME: package_two
PACKAGE LOCATION: ./package_two
PACKAGE VERSION: 0.2.1

PACKAGE NAME: package_three
PACKAGE LOCATION: ./package_three
PACKAGE VERSION: 1.3.4

PACKAGE NAME: package_one
PACKAGE LOCATION: ./package_one
PACKAGE VERSION: 0.1.2
```

My search script currently looks as followed:

```
<?
$search = $_POST['search']; //Passed from a user input form

$data_file = file('http://www.example.com/data_file.txt'); //The text file repository

    $final_concatenated_results = "";

    for ($i = 0, $found = FALSE; isset($data_file[$i]); $i++) {
        if (trim($data_file[$i]) === $search) { 
        $cleanse = trim($data_file[++$i]);
        $output_part_one = strstr($cleanse, '.');
        $output_part_two = "http://www.example.com/packages_repository/".$output_part_one;
        $add_this = "<a href='$output_part_two'>$output_part_two</a>"."<br/>";
        $found = TRUE;
        $final_concatenated_results.=$add_this;
    } }

    if ($found == TRUE) {
        echo $final_results;
    }

    if ($found == FALSE) {
        echo "Error, package not found.";
    }
?>
```

For example, if "PACKAGE NAME: package_two" were typed in verbatim this would be the output -- http://www.example.com/packages_repository/./package_one which works fine.

Ideally, I'd like to know how to change my code so instead of typing in "PACKAGE NAME: package_two", one could simply type in "package_two" or even some like "two" or "tw". How much tweaking would that need?

Also, I made a variable to concatenate all of the resulting URLs to one string, so if "package_one" were searched, it would return two URLS... I don't think I did the code right as it only produces the one URL.

** I should mention that immediately after the package name is matched, it finds the next string following "PACKAGE LOCATION: ." to grab the URL

Any input is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are looking for an exact match:

```
if (trim($data_file[$i]) === $search) {
```

You can use [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to see if your search string appears in the line:

```
if (stripos($data_file[$i], $search) !== FALSE) {
```

Note that you need the `!==` comparison because `stripos` can evaluate to 0.

Comment: I see where you're going. If the user typed in "package_tw" ... is there a way to treat that as a "package_two" match? Also, would be it easier/possible for me to explode(); the whole file so each line was an array index and I could then do the the stripos(); searching and add one to that line's index and use preg_replace(); to remove the "LOCATION: " part from output? Thanks, jeroen!

Comment: @user1062058 `package_tw` with the code above will match `package_two`, `package_twenty`, `PACKAGE_twO`, etc. About the other questions, they seem unrelated to the search part, so perhaps you'd better ask it in another question or specify the exact output you are looking for in the original one.

Comment: Okay, thank you jeroen. I noticed my question here is currently ranked #3 on google when you search about this topic... your answer will be of much help to others. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the strpos() function:

```
if(strpos(trim($data_file[$i],$search) != false)
```

It checks if your search string (the needle) is inside the haystack (your current input line).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm looking into the strpos(); now!

Comment: For user-input the stripos() in the other answer seems to be the better solution, as it's case insensitive.